# Synchronization when using InputStream

Tags: java, synchronization, mapreduce, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader

I need to implement a short Map-Reduce program. One of the operations I need to do is split a txt file in X parts, so that each part will be used as input on my Map function when I only do read operations on the file fragments.

I could split the file in more local files and use each file as input on the Map function. But I'm thinking of trying this solution: split the file in X Scanners built using InputStream at different locations in the file.

Will I have synchronization problems when each thread uses the Scanner objects? Is it going to be slower because each thread is trying to access the same file?

Comment: You could read whole file to the string object and then share this string object between different locations. Or I'm wrong understand what you need. Post some code...

Comment: if the OP needs to use map/reduce to process the file, i doubt it fits in memory...

Answer (score 0):

In principle, if you're careful then you should be able to do this *if* the operating system lets you. I would recommend that for each thread, open a BufferedReader on the file, then get the respective FileChannel object (via BufferedReader.getChannel()) and **lock the portion that that thread intends to process** (see FileChannel.lock()). Provided the O/S lets you get this far, I think you shouldn't have any actual problem.

However, I wonder if there's much performance benefit in doing things this way. If you can, I suspect it may be better from a performance point of view to **have a single thread doing the actual reading serially through the file, and then farming sequential lines as appropriate to a thread pool** operating a Scanner per thread.

Comment: why do you need to lock the file to read it?  nowhere does the OP's question mention that the file might be changing while being read.

Comment: @jtahlborn, that's correct. Another way of putting it is, do we need synchronization when multiple threads read from the same file?

Comment: @Cookie503 - no you don't.  why would you need synchronization if the file is unchanging?